# Set A Lower P-State For My CPU (Underclocking)

Tags: 13.10, cpu

In Windows 8 you can set a max/min cpu speed percentage allowing you to use your cpu at a lower or higher P-State. For example, my cpu has a default speed of 2.3ghz (turbo 3.2ghz), however using the max/min settings I can underclock it to a stable 1.36ghz (which appears to be the lowest supported setting on my cpu?). How can I do this under Ubuntu 13.10? I would prefer a non-terminal command method if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would use CPUFreq

I used CPUFreq in order to under-clock my processor in my laptop. Unfortunately, my laptop had an nForce motherboard chipset, and I couldn't undervolt my processor with the traditional Intel methods... and that was all there was. However I was from a 2.4GHz to 1.6 drop, and that helped reduce the heat and power consumption in my laptop.

Download `cpufreq` from the repository.

Open a terminal as `root` or use `sudo`:
Code:

```
cpufreq-info
```

to view your profiles and
Code:

```
cpufreq-set
```

to set your profiles.

Use
Code:

```
cpufreq-set -h
```

To determine what to put in the command line.

Comment: worked for me, I c/p it from other site